# What happens if the power supply of an op-amp is connected to ground?

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier

[image]

[image]

This question is from one of the past papers of the exam I am studying for.

I don't understand what it really means to connect an operational amplifier's energy supply to ground. I thought in this case v<sub>o</sub> can only be 0 since it must be between -supply and +supply.

In addition to that, for (b), I probably did something wrong because I didn't end up with a linear function over any interval.

I couldn't really do much about this problem but here is what I tried:

[image]

Any help and explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual wording of the question? Details matter.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The whole question is given at the top of the question, there is nothing given other than that. I also corrected a misunderstanding of mine by changing the grounded resistor to R1 from R2 because that was the way I tried to solve it.

Comment: The chip has two power supply pins. So the singular form is suspect. But if it's an ideal op-amp with 0V supplies, output will be 0V. Real ones will behave somewhat differently.

Comment: What are Vsat and -Vsat? The supplies? But op-amp one pin is ground. And no other supply pin shown. The op-amp is also said to be ideal so is it still limited by something if some mystery pin is ground?

Comment: @Justme I just read that, too, but I assumed that they were over-riding the schematic and just saying that in this case a bipolar supply is to now be considered with those limits. For earlier questions I wanted to assume that the bottom rail was 0 V and the top rail was 'unlimited'.

Comment: If the original values of R1 and R2 are used, this constitutes a differential amplifier with gain of 2.

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve op-amp equations is to set the terminal voltages of v+ v- to be equal. Very little current travels into the op-amp nodes (ideal op-amps it's zero current)

You can then solve the equations normally.

But to answer your question about power of the op amp. The op-amp is a collection of transistors, for the transistors to operate, they connected to a high voltage rail and a low voltage rail, the output will be between the rails if operating conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would like to learn that if rails should be something like +A and -A or their magnitudes can vary like +A and -B. Because in this case, assuming voltage of ground = 0, v_0 will be equal to 0. I am not sure about my answer for (a) but seems like this is the case. I also don't know what to do about (b) because it doesn't have any linear relation on any interval. Could you please help me with that one as well?

Comment: It really depends on what they mean by the bottom port, it could be a reference pin if the amplifier is an instrumention amp. It could be a power rail. If only the ground is connected you'll get 0v on the output. But in general academic questions usually don't use rails. If this is an analysis question then the probably want to derive the diff amp equations from vout = Av (v+ - v-)